# How to appropriately give attribution (CC BY 2.5) for splash image on landing page

Tags: licenses

I plan to use a splash image licensed by the CC BY 2.5 for a website's landing page.

> Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the
> license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any
> reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor
> endorses you or your use.

I wonder if it would be okay if I provide the name of the author and a link to the image's license (stored in Wiki Commons) in smaller font size (Small but still legible) below the slogan on my landing page.

Comment: For reference: [Best practices for attribution - Creative Commons](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution) , however it doesn't address where that attribution needs to occur as far as I can see.

Comment: Similar question on Photography Stack Exchange: [How to attribute Flickr Creative Commons photos online?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/how-to-attribute-flickr-creative-commons-photos-online)

Comment: Should this be closed?

Comment: We don't necessarily close questions just because they are answered elsewhere on the web.    This is a question that is relevant to webmasters and could still use an answer here.

Comment: Okay, you are right, thanks for keeping it here.